# A locally convex $C^*$ algebra without zero divisor

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ra.rings-and-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let  we have a locally convex $C^*$ algebra $A$. That is  $A$ is a  TVS equipped with an algebra  and  an involution structure such that all operations are  continuous. Moreover the topology on  $A$ is given by a familly of $C^*$ semi norms.

Is it obvious that $A$ has at least one  zero  divisor?

Motivation: In every $C^*$ algebra there always exist zero divisors.More important motivation: the importance of locally convex algebra described in the litterature plz see the book by A. Ya. Helemskii. Banach  and locally convex algebras.

Comment: Can't you just make the obvious functional calculus argument in this setting?  What is the obstruction?

Comment: @NikWeaver Does the integrals exist in TVS? I vaguely remember some theorem from functional analysis Rudin they  guarantee existence of integral for  banach spaces but i am not sure for TVS. On the other hand I vaguely remember  some thing about non triviality of zero divisors in topological C^* algebras. In the standard case we have $a_+a_-=0$ what do you think about topological case?

Comment: @NikWeaver So if you are sure the answer is obviously negative, this would prevent me to ask  my next following question: is there a  locally convex  structure on the disk algebra via a family of  C^*  semi norms  and  an involution making it a  topoogical C^* algebra

Comment: @NikWeaver  what condition we should add for "completeness" other wise the space of real analytic function on the unit disk with the standard involution does not have zero divisor

Comment: I guess I was assuming a "C* seminorm" should be complete, is that not your definition?

Comment: @NikWeaver  Yes I just reinvestigate my definition I just realized we assume every seminorm is complete. So  this question arises: what is a gelfand Naimark analogy  here:  characterization of all  LCS  C^* algebras?

Comment: I don't know. You might try working out the commutative case first.