# A locally convex $C^*$ algebraic structure on the disk algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

A locally convex $C^*$ algebra is a locally convex topological vector space $A$ whose topology is generated by a familly of complete $C^*$ semi norm and $A$ is a $*$ algebra. Moreover all algebra operations and involution are continuous operators(A complete $C^*$ semi norm is a semi norm which satisfies $|xx^*|=|x|^2$ and is a complete semi norm).
Locally convex Banach algebras is introduced in "Banach and locally convex algebras" by A.Ya. Helemeskii

**Question:** Is there a locally convex $C^*$ algebraic structure on the disk algebra $A(\mathbb{D})$?

The disk algebra is the Banach algebra of all holomorphic functions on the interior of the unit disk with continuous extention the boundary of the disk.

A motivation for this question is the following post:

[A locally convex $C^*$ algebra without zero divisor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422949/a-locally-convex-c-algebra-without-zero-divisor)

Comment: It is rather unusual to have a **complete** seminorm $p$ on Fréchet space $X$ because then the the quotient map $X\to (X,p)/\mathrm{kern}(p)$ would be open (because the quotient is a Banach space). Such Fréchet spaces are called **quojections** and very close to products of Banach spaces.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth  Thank you very much for your comments and your attention to my question.

Comment: Ali, I must say that I don't understand what is meant by "complete seminorm".

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov   Sergei  I mean that the quotint space is complete.

Comment: Ah, OK! $\phantom{-----}$